# How to 'trace' areas from the layer below?

Tags: qgis, vector

I have some Ordnance Survey vector data for my local area. I want to create a new layer and on it 'trace' some of the areas, fields, verges etc from the layer below with the intention of then colouring the areas I have traced. I am sure I saw a tutorial or instructions for this somewhere but can no longer find it.

Using QGIS Lisboa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tutorial about digitizing polygons in QGIS:

http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2011/12/digitizing-in-qgis.html

Comment: Accepting this as the answer as this was immediately useful to me and though Neil Hopton's paper, referenced above, is also an answer this one was the easiest for me to use immediately.

Comment: @NigelLaw: although I've never have any experience with Ordnance Survey vector data, since it's vector data, IMHO, you should reduce your work load as much as possible by copying or using Polygonizer Plug-in to convert existed data as in *nhopton*'s answer.

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth having a look at this too:
http://confound.me.uk/maps/ppv4.pdf

Comment: Thank you for this Neil, a useful addition to Cao Minh Tu's answer.